# how do I display a blinking caret in an NSView?

Tags: cocoa

I'm building a custom NSView subclass that displays and edit's text - I've got to the bit to display a blinking caret - I can't find a reference anywhere - could someone point me to the function or a reference? (In windows I'd do ShowCaret - piece of cake). tia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to do this, then you would have to implement it yourself. Your view should have a boolean ivar to store the current blink state and you'll need to use a repeating timer to do something like this in your timer method:

```
- (void)updateCaret:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    caretBlinkActive = !caretBlinkActive; //this sets the blink state
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:[self caretRect]];
}
```

You'd need to implement `caretRect` to return the current caret rectangle.

In your implementation of `drawRect:` you'd need to optimise drawing so that only the dirty rect is drawn, and you'd use the value of `caretBlinkActive` to either draw the caret or not.

To create the timer in the first place you'd do something like:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:caretBlinkRate 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(updateCaret:) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `NSTextView`? You'd get this behavior for free.

Comment: Yup, and you can guarantee that `NSTextView` will work about one blue whale unit better than a custom view built from scratch. It's had a ***lot*** of engineering time spent on it by very good engineers.

Comment: If I wanted to use NSTextView I would. There are a number of features NSTextView doesn't support.

Comment: OK, 1. NSView doesn't run on the IPad. 2. I'm porting from Windows - I need a minimal compatibility layer - changing to NSView means a big rewrite. 3. The apple docs recommend not using NSView if you have more than 100 sub views - I do. 4. I will no doubt hit some feature that NSView doesn't support and then I'm stuck. 5. There are more, but that should cover it. Really Core text does all I need, and is fairly easy. All I want to do is have a flashing Caret but it seems I have to do this myself with a timer and so on.

Comment: replace NSView with NSTextView in the above

Comment: You mentioned nothing about the iPad in your original question, and your question is tagged `cocoa` and you mention `NSView`, which is a Mac API. Is it any surprise that people are suggesting `NSTextView`?